# Django Media-File Download-Link opening preview

Tags: django, amazon-s3, django-templates, wagtail, django-media

I have a Django project in which I use wagtail. Now on one page, the user can upload an image and download it later. For the download link, I used following html:

```
  <a href="{{file.document.url}}" class="text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-900" download target="_blank">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-download text-black" viewBox="0 0 16 16"> 
      <path d="M.5 9.9a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v2.5a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h12a1 1 0 0 0 1-1v-2.5a.5.5 0 0 1 1 0v2.5a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H2a2 2 0 0 1-2-2v-2.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5z"/> 
      <path d="M7.646 11.854a.5.5 0 0 0 .708 0l3-3a.5.5 0 0 0-.708-.708L8.5 10.293V1.5a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0v8.793L5.354 8.146a.5.5 0 1 0-.708.708l3 3z"/> 
    </svg>
  </a>
```

On my local device when running with `python manage.py runserver`, this code works fine and every image gets downloaded. On my Environment, it doesn't work that well. Every image and pdf is opened in a preview first, from where the user has to manually save the image.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Just to confirm - are you using Wagtail's Documents feature for the image upload? Also, are you using a remote file storage backend such as Amazon S3? And have you changed any of the document settings (listed at https://docs.wagtail.org/en/latest/reference/settings.html#documents) from their defaults?

Comment: @gasman it is handled by AWS S3, and I didn't set it up so I have no clue how this works... Is there any special stuff to do to download files from s3?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to configure S3 to return a `Content-Disposition: attachment` header on the files it serves, to tell the browser to force a download instead of rendering files in-browser. Based on the [django-storages](https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html) docs (assuming that's the library you're using) and [the boto3 docs linked from there](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3/client/put_object.html), I believe adding the following to your project settings should set this for newly-uploaded files (unfortunately it won't affect ones that are already uploaded):

```
AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {"ContentDisposition": "attachment"}
```